# Symbols already defined with C++ templates used by static and shared libraries

Tags: c++, templates, shared-libraries, static-libraries, duplicate-symbol

I have the following problem in my project that contains several modules (I am sorry but I could not find a simpler example) :

- *Module1* defines a full template class *ILocatable*
- *Module2* defines a class *Component*
- *Module3* defines a class *LocatableEntity* that inherits from *ILocatable < MyVector3D>* (here, *MyVector3D* is an *std::array<double,3>*)
- *Module4a* uses modules 1,2,3, and defines a class *LocatableComponent4a* which inherits from *Component* and *ILocatable < MyVector3D >* that uses *LocatableEntity*
- *Module4b* uses modules 1,2,3,4a, a defines a class *LocatableComponent4b* which inherits from *Component* and *ILocatable < MyVector3D >* and uses *LocatableComponent4a* and *LocatableEntity*

*Module1* and *Module3* are *static* libraries.
*Module2*, *Module4a*, *Module4b* are *shared* libraries.
All modules compile fine except *Module4b* where I get the following error (with Visual C++, not with Linux/GCC) :

> Project5_Module4a.lib(Project5_Module4a.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __cdecl Project5::Module1::ILocatable<class std::array<double,3> >::~ILocatable<class std::array<double,3> >(void)" (??1?$ILocatable@V?$array@N$02@std@@@Module1@Project5@@UEAA@XZ) déjà défini(e) dans Project5_Module3.lib(LocatableEntity.obj)

Please not that in Debug mode, there are more duplicate symbols (one for each method of *ILocatable*)

How can I cope with this ?
When *Module3* is linked dynamically the problem disappears, but I really would like to keep the static libraries.
I also tried to instanciate the template with *std::array<double,3>* in *Module3* but :

- This didn't solve my problem
- Most of the users of my project shall use other instanciations, such as *Eigen::Vector3d* or *osg::Vec3d* or whatever.

Many thanks for any help !!!

The full project is available here : https://ufile.io/1tkrt6d6 (needs CMake).
Here are some parts of code :

```
    namespace Module1 {
        template <class Vector3D>
        class ILocatable {
        protected:
            inline ILocatable() {
                this->position[0] = 0.0; this->position[1] = 0.0; this->position[2] = 0.0;
                this->frame = Frame::WGS84;
            }
        public:
            virtual inline ~ILocatable() {}
            inline const Vector3D& getPosition() const { return this->position; }
            inline void setPosition(const Vector3D& value) { this->position = value; }
            inline Frame getFrame() const { return this->frame; }
            inline void setFrame(Frame value) { this->frame = value; }
        private:
            Vector3D position;
            Frame frame;
        };
    } // namespace Module1
```

```
    namespace Module3 {
        typedef std::array<double, 3> MyVector3D;
        class Project5_Module3_EXPORT LocatableEntity : public Module1::ILocatable<MyVector3D> {
        public:
            LocatableEntity();
            virtual ~LocatableEntity();
        };
    } // namespace
```

```
    namespace Module4a {
        typedef std::array<double, 3> MyVector3D;
        class Project5_Module4a_EXPORT LocatableComponent4a : public Module2::Component, public Module1::ILocatable<MyVector3D> {
        public:
            LocatableComponent4a();
            virtual ~LocatableComponent4a();
            void move() {
                Module3::LocatableEntity locatableEntity;
                locatableEntity.setPosition(this->getPosition());
                locatableEntity.setFrame(this->getFrame());
                Module3::move(locatableEntity);
                this->setPosition(locatableEntity.getPosition());
                this->setFrame(locatableEntity.getFrame());
            }
        };
    } // namespace Module4a
```

```
    namespace Module4b {
        typedef std::array<double, 3> MyVector3D;
        class Project5_Module4b_EXPORT LocatableComponent4b : public Module2::Component, public Module1::ILocatable<MyVector3D> {
        public:
            LocatableComponent4b();
            virtual ~LocatableComponent4b();
            void move();
            void join(const Module4a::LocatableComponent4a& otherComponent) {
                this->setPosition(otherComponent.getPosition());
                this->setFrame(otherComponent.getFrame());
            }
        };
    } // namespace Module4b
```

Comment: Did you define`ILocatable::~ILocatable` anywhere else or used explicit specialization or explicit instantiation? If so, please add where you instantiated/specialized the templates. Form a [mre].

Comment: *ILocatable::~ILocatable* is not defined anywhere else.
All specializations/instanciations were given in the original post : _LocatableEntity_, _LocatableComponent4a_ and _LocatableComponent4b_.
The complete and reproducible example is available here : https://ufile.io/1tkrt6d6 (needs CMake).